# Can we add variables and create new functions?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I did not know how to formulate the title, but I try to phrase the question like this:

Say I have a vector $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2)$ and a function $f(\mathbf{a})=f(a_1,a_2)$, such that $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Next, say I also have a vector $\mathbf{b}=(b_1,b_2)$ and a function $g(\mathbf{b})=g(b_1,b_2)$, such that $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

And now I add the vectors, $\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}=(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2)$ and I have a function $h(\mathbf{c})=\dots???$ 
But hey, what happens here?

Is $h$ now a function of four variables, i.e. $h(\mathbf{c})=h(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2)$? 
Or what does $h(\mathbf{c})=h(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2)$ mean?

Comment: It the domain of $h$ is $\mathbb R^2$ (as it seems here) then it is a function on $2$ real variables, period. The fact that its argument can be written as a sum (actually sums, because for a fixed $c$ there are more possibilities to write $c=a+b$) of two does not affect that.

Comment: How could something like, say, $h\bigl((7,3)\bigr)$ be determined?

Answer (score 1):

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$tl; dr: A function $y = f(x)$ is not its output value $y$, but a *relationship* between two variables, $x$ and $y$. You're implicitly using the same letter $h$ to denote two different functions, one of two variables and one of four variables.

---

To a modern mathematician, if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, then a *function* $f:X \to Y$ is a subset $\Gamma$ of the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ such that *for every $x$ in $X$, there exists a **unique** $y$ in $Y$ such that $(x, y) \in \Gamma$*.

Less formally, a function is a *rule* associating a unique *value* $y = f(x)$ to each $x$ in $X$.

Even less specifically (but getting at what seems to be the crux of the question), a function is a *relationship between two quantities*, where the term "quantity" should be interpreted liberally as "an element of some set" (not necessarily a set of real numbers).

(*Caution*: Loose historical claims.) This understanding of functions is relatively recent: The stringent legel definition above comes from the 20th century, while the viewpoint that a function is a single-valued relation emerged in the 19th century.

Mathematicians of prior eras, as well as physicists and engineers and calculus textbooks of today that use Leibniz notation, often focus on the *variables* or *quantities* themselves, as in, "Let $x = x(t)$ be the position of a particle at time $t$", or "Let $A = A(x, y)$ be the area of a rectangle of width $x$ and height $y$." (There are good Leibniz-notational reasons for this practice, but the notation comes at a price, particularly the large number of spurious "paradoxes" and other confusions regarding partial derivatives and the chain rule. But I digress.)

Your question is predicated on a "variables-based" viewpoint regarding functions. When you write "$\Vec{c} = \Vec{a} + \Vec{b}$", and "$h(\Vec{c}) = h(a_{1} + b_{1}, a_{2} + b_{2})$", and "Is $h$ now a function of four variables, i.e. $h(\Vec{c}) = h(a_{1}, a_{2}, b_{1}, b_{2})$? Or what does $h(\Vec{c}) = h(a_{1} + b_{1}, a_{2} + b_{2})$ mean?" there is (as I read it) an implicit assumption that "a function is its value".

Explicitly, one might be tempted to write $\Vec{y} = h(\Vec{c}) = h(a_{1} + b_{1}, a_{2} + b_{2}) = h(a_{1}, a_{2}, b_{1}, b_{2})$, and then ask whether $\Vec{y}$ is a function of two variables or of four.

The mathematical problem is, such an equation uses the symbol "$h$" to stand for two (or three, if you distinguish $\Reals^{2}$ and $\Reals \times \Reals$) *distinct functions* (relationships between variables). To disambiguate, a modern mathematician might write
$$
\Vec{y} = h(a_{1} + b_{1}, a_{2} + b_{2}) = H(a_{1}, a_{2}, b_{1}, b_{2}),
$$
with $H:\Reals^{4} \to \Reals$ defined by the second equality. The resolution to your question would then be, "$h$ is a function of two variables and $H$ is a function of four variables, and these functions are distinct", though they are themselves closely related: $h(\Vec{a} + \Vec{b}) = H(\Vec{a}, \Vec{b})$. (In the spirit of hair-splitting, we're now identifying $\Reals^{4}$ and $\Reals^{2} \times \Reals^{2}$.)$\endgroup$